# What could be the possible reason that an ARM register gets polluted?

Tags: arm, cpu-registers, neon

Recently I ran into this strange issue(Thumb2 instr-set). Say I have following code:

```
000a8948 <some_func>:
a8948:       e92d 4ff0       stmdb   sp!, {r4, r5, r6, r7, r8, r9, sl, fp, lr}
a894c:       460f            mov     r7, r1
a894e:       f8df 8260       ldr.w   r8, [pc, #608]
a8952:       4606            mov     r6, r0       --> r0 shows b89a8408 in backtrace
a8954:       4b97            ldr     r3, [pc, #604]
a8956:       f100 0410       add.w   r4, r0, #16  --> only place r4 gets assigned, but it can't be 0.
a895a:       44f8            add     r8, pc
a895c:       f04f 0900       mov.w   r9, #0
a8960:       ed2d 8b04       vpush   {d8-d9}
a8964:       f858 1003       ldr.w   r1, [r8, r3]
a8968:       b095            sub     sp, #84 ; 0x54
a896a:       f8df b24c       ldr.w   fp, [pc, #588]
a896e:       ad0c            add     r5, sp, #48
a8970:       f8df c248       ldr.w   ip, [pc, #584]
a8974:       f8df a248       ldr.w   sl, [pc, #584]
a8978:       ed9f 8b8b       vldr    d8, [pc, #556]
a897c:       680a            ldr     r2, [r1, #0]
a897e:       44fb            add     fp, pc
a8980:       44fc            add     ip, pc
a8982:       44fa            add     sl, pc
a8984:       9107            str     r1, [sp, #28]
a8986:       9213            str     r2, [sp, #76]
a8988:       6823            ldr     r3, [r4, #0]     // ERR: SIGSEGV happens, code 1 (SEGV_MAPPER), fault addr 0x0
```

So when this issue happens, r4 turned to value 0, what I cannot figure out is that how r4 gets polluted, given it only be assigned to r0+16 at line a8956? Could it be that Neon instructions write r4 somehow?

Comment: What is " ldr.w   ip, [pc, #584]"? It looks like the disassembler is not set to the correct instruction set and the instructions you see are wrong. Did you write the code or are you disassembling object code? In other words, that routine looks like giberish.

Comment: @BitBank it's a load from (presumably) the literal pool at the end of the function (584 bytes ahead), into r12 (ip), which being a high register needs the wide (.w) encoding. This kind of demented register juggling suggests compiled code of a relatively complex routine in a fairly high-level language.

Comment: @BitBank, it's dissambled by objdump -DC <.so>

Comment: To be more clear, this code is generated by Android ART compiler.

Comment: Can't you simply use your debugger to do instruction stepping, and watch carefully the value of R4?

Comment: Is it possible that you are branching into this code from some other address that isn't shown here?

Comment: @Bregalad, this issue is hard to reproduce, I have yet reproduce it locally. So never get a chance to dig into using debugger...

Comment: @Pete Fordham, it's a good point. Just it's really hard to figure from where...